# WCF - The remote server returned an error: NotFound (Only happens on 1 specific call)

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, silverlight

I know multiple questions have been asked on this specific error message, but none of them were relevant to what I am experiencing.

I have a Silverlight & WCF project. I am making calls to the wcf service and retrieving data just fine. I have multiple functions in my service and they all work great.

My problem is, I make a call to function that I just created and I get the "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" error message. No clue why. I've built the wcf project and updated the service in silverlight. Error List doesn't show anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

I have a class level variable which is my web service.

Code in Silverlight:

```
Private WithEvents Service As WebService.SQLServiceClient = GetNewService()

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim View As PagedCollectionView = dgDeficiences.ItemsSource

    Service.SaveChangesAsync(txtLOB.Text, View.SourceCollection)
End Sub
```

Code in WCF:

```
<OperationContract()>
Public Function SaveChanges(ByVal LOB As String, ByVal Deficiences As List(Of Deficiences)) As Boolean
    Dim DT_Old, DT_New, DT_Changes As DataTable
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(String.Empty, Conn)

    DT_Old = GetSQLData(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "EHL_GetLookups", {"Section", "Data"}, {3, LOB})

    If DT_Old.Rows.Count < 1 Then Return False

    'Copy deficiencies in sql to DT_New
    DT_New = DT_Old.Copy

    'Update 3 fields with data user provided
    For i As Integer = 0 To Deficiences.Count - 1
        'Find deficiency row to update by ID field
        For j As Integer = 0 To DT_New.Rows.Count - 1
            If DT_New.Rows(j)("DeficiencyID") = Deficiences(i).DeficiencyID Then
                DT_New.Rows(j)("Status") = Deficiences(i).Status
                DT_New.Rows(j)("PatternOfCare") = Deficiences(i).PatternOfCare
                DT_New.Rows(j)("MarketNarrative") = Deficiences(i).MarketNarrative

                Continue For 'Next Deficiency
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Set primary key so merge works correctly
    DT_Old.PrimaryKey = {DT_Old.Columns("DeficiencyID")}
    DT_New.PrimaryKey = {DT_New.Columns("DeficiencyID")}

    'Make sure all row status = unchanges
    DT_Old.AcceptChanges()

    'Merge user's changes to data in database
    DT_Old.Merge(DT_New)

    'Get rows with changes 
    DT_Changes = DT_Old.GetChanges()

    'Save changes to SQL
    For i As Integer = 0 To DT_Changes.Rows.Count - 1
        Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.EHL_Deficiency_NewEHLTest " _
                        & "SET Status='" & DT_Changes.Rows(i)("Status") & "', Pattern_Of_Care='" & DT_Changes.Rows(i)("PatternOfCare") & "', Market_Narrative='" & DT_Changes.Rows(i)("PatternOfCare") & "' " _
                        & "WHERE DeficiencyID=" & DT_Changes.Rows(i)("DeficiencyID")

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    If DT_Changes.Rows.Count < 1 Then Return False Else Return True
End Function
```

Comment: "I make a call to function that I **just created**" - did you update the service reference in your Silverlight project after you added the function?

Comment: Yes and I know it did, because in the button click event. It showed under the Service variable.

Comment: are you sure your web config is pointing you at the same location as you are using to generate the reference?

Comment: I reuse the class level variable "Service" in the same page and it works in other subs. I don't see how the web config has anything to do with it.

Comment: After playing around with this for sometime now. I realized I only get this issue when I have a List as a parameter. When I removed the list, the function fired on the web service (of course it didnt work). I guess my next step is to figure out how to send a list to WCF?

Answer (score 0):

In your config file of your start-up project you should have an entry like so

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="ENDPOINT Address"
        (other stuff)
      </endpoint>
```

verify that the endpoint address is pointing at the same instance that you used to generate the reference. If you service reference is not in your start-up project then you need to copy the (correct) config entries from the project with the reference to your start-up project.

Comment: Yes, the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file. I have 2 endpoints. One for when I launch locally (localhost) and another for when it's published to the web server. In the code-behind, based on the URI, I select which endpoint to use. I get the same error locally and when I publish and visit the site. The service works because it returns data to me. It's baffling that this one function is the only one that shows that error.

Answer (score 0):

With silverlight its a very common error, firstly the error u r getting is a generic error which silverlight application shows for any service side error.
Now the solution, try the find out the root cause of this error.
There are various ways of doing this.
Below is the one which i used for mine:
1) Add the below piece of code to ur config file of the wcf service
 Collapse | Copy Code
`<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "D:\Sumit.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>`

this will generate an .svc, analyse this file it will provide you with a lot of information.

2) U can use external tools for analysing the wcf service calls, such as fiddler. In this case also try to analyse the service calls